# Qliksense how to search for a string across multiple text columns Logical OR

Tags: filter, qliksense, inputbox, action-button, qlik-expression

I have seen the answer to this attempted across multiple sources, but many of the solutions seem outdated or to simply not work or are Qlikview instead of qliksense such as: https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/Select-all-fields-where-value-occur/td-p/477350.
https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/Button-to-select-multiple-fields-with-logical-OR/td-p/832431

I have several descriptive text fields in my data table. I would like for the ability to search for a string across all 5 fields and filter the data table accordingly if the string is in field1 OR field2 OR field3, etc.I know how to accomplish this via AND but not OR... My search string is coming from an inputbox. I believe I need to use an action button, but I am having trouble connecting the dots. Here is what I tried (but I think this may only be applicable to qlikview:

```
Button -> select values matching search criteria -> '=field1= like ' & chr(39) & '*$(vInputBox)*' & chr(39) & ' or field2 like ' & chr(39) & '*$(vInputBox)*' & chr(39)
```

Any pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! I am pretty desperate for an answer to this